# Camel Restlet and CXF SOA Integration Issue

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel, gson, restlet

I am new to Camel and am facing an issue with a route I need to setup. It will be great if someone can either guide me to the correct forum or better still rectify the issue I am facing. 
Here is what I need to do - expose a restlet endpoint to accept data; use this data as input to an external SOAP web service and send back the response in JSON format back to the caller... 
Here is what I have done...however, I am getting the following error while Camel tries to call the Web Service...can anyone guide me here? Thanks.

I am using camel 2.11.1 and cxf-codegen-plugin version 2.7.11

I am getting the following exception: org.restlet.data.Parameter cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

```
    public class IntegrationTest extends CamelTestSupport { 

String restletURL = <url>;

    @org.junit.Test 
    public void integTest() throws Exception { 
    //trying to simulate the rest service call... 
  template.sendBodyAndHeader(restletURL, "Body does not matter here", "data", "{\"FromCurrency\":\"AUD\",\"ToCurrency\":\"USD\"}"); 

    } 


    @Override 
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception { 
        return new RouteBuilder() { 
            @Override 
            public void configure() throws Exception { 
            System.out.println("In Counfigure"); 

        String cxfEndpoint = "cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?" 
        + "wsdlURL=http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl&" 
        + "serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertor&" 
        + "portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertorSoap&" 
        + "dataFormat=MESSAGE"; 

        XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat(); 
        SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("net.webservicex", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(CurrencyConvertorSoap.class, true)); 

         GsonDataFormat gson = new GsonDataFormat(ConversionRate.class); 
         gson.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);

from(restletURL).routeId("Restlet") 
                                .process(new Processor() { 
                                        @Override 
                                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
                                                String data = (String) URLDecoder.decode((String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("data"), "UTF-8"); 
                                                System.out.println(data); 
                                                // get the mail body as a String 
                                                exchange.getIn().setBody(data); 
                                                Response.getCurrent().setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK); 
                                } 

                                }) 
                .unmarshal(gson) 
                .marshal(soap) 
                .log("${body}") 
                .to(cxfEndpoint) 
                .unmarshal(soap) 
                .marshal(xmlJsonFormat); 
                .log("${body}"); 
            } 
        }; 
    } 
}
```

However, the sample works when I try out the individual pieces - restlet alone and CXF alone...

Thanks,
Ritwick.

Comment: Here is the complete exception stack (I was not allowed to enter 2 links in the original question:2014-07-01 13:33:00,228 [stlet-963335244] WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain          - Interceptor for {http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertor#{http://www.webserviceX.NET/}ConversionRate has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.ClassCastException: ClassCastException invoking http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx: org.restlet.data.Parameter cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: If you do the marshal and unmarshal work yourself, you can just use camel-http component to redirect the request to real back end service. You don't need to use camel-cxf this time.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I am going to try to use the camel-servlet component to do the work for the camel-restlet component. Still working on it...let's see how that goes.

Comment: Hi William, I was able to achieve what I needed by using the camel-servlet component. Thanks for your guidance. Thanks, Ritwick

Comment: Hi William, I was able to make the restlet thing work as well...all it needed was an additional line exchange.getIn().setHeader("org.restlet.http.headers", ""); Once I added that, the route worked like a charm. Thanks for your help. Ritwick.

Answer (score 2):

Sure Willem, here is the entire configure implementation:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
        String restletURL = "restlet:http://localhost:8080/convert/{data}?restletMethods=get";

        String cxfEndpoint = "cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?"
                + "portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertorSoap&"
                + "dataFormat=MESSAGE&loggingFeatureEnabled=true&defaultOperationName=ConversionRate&defaultOperationNamespace={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}&synchronous=true";


        SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("net.webservicex", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(CurrencyConvertorSoap.class, true));
        soap.setVersion("1.2");

        GsonDataFormat gson = new GsonDataFormat(ConversionRate.class);
        gson.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);

        from(restletURL).routeId("Restlet")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String data = (String) URLDecoder.decode((String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("data"), "UTF-8");
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("org.restlet.http.headers", "");
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("data", "");
                exchange.getIn().setBody(data);
                Response.getCurrent().setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
            }

        })
        .unmarshal(gson)
        .marshal(soap)
        .to(cxfEndpoint)
        .unmarshal(soap)
        .marshal(gson)
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String output = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.getOut().setBody(output);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ritwick for posting the solution at that time, it helped me now.

Comment: @UmairSaleem, I am glad the post was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was facing has been resolved. In addition to "exchange.getIn().setBody(data);", I added the following line of code "exchange.getIn().setHeader("org.restlet.http.headers", "");" in order to get rid of the class cast exception I was getting. The restlet headers were causing this issue and once these headers were removed (I didn't need the headers in the first place), everything worked as expected.

Thanks,
Ritwick.

Comment: Can you share camel route with us?